# Scroll to the bottom of a div after an element as loaded?

Tags: jquery, html

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918787/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-div-even-after-it-updates), I also have a page with a div that fills up with chat-style bubbles on click - each click makes one new "bubble" appear. They're all contained in a .content div that does not have a set height.

However, the page does not automatically scroll down if one of the bubbles loads below the height of the browser window, and I've had a couple people complain that they didn't know there was anymore content that was supposed to load.

As recommended in the question I posted, I've tried adding this script to the end of my page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").click(function() {
            $(".content").animate({ scrollTop: $(".content")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    });
});
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything at all... Am I missing something obvious?

I set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuckyeah/ek922tz2/1/) too, taking out the effect of each bubble loading on click. The effect of scrolling down to the bottom of the div on click though doesn't seem to work either. I'm a super newbie and trying to figure this all out, so any help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried putting `overflow: auto` on your `div.content` ?

Comment: I did try that, still no dice though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my updates

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".content")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buithehoa/ek922tz2/5/)